# Java program where user inputs numbers to print a trident in the output

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop, substring

I am very new to programming, and for this program I'm stumped on how to get started. I was just wondering if there is a simple way to write this program using if & else statements, string & substrings, and while loops.
I need to print a trident using asterisks by using three parameters:

- t = height of the tines
- s = spacing between the tines
- h = length of the handle

I need a user input. Also, you can assume that t, s, h are each at least 0 and not larger than 10.

For example:

```
Sample Input:
4
3
2

Sample Output:
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   *   *
*********
    *
    *
```

Comment: Have you tried formulating the algorithm? For example, how many loops you would need, what would be the conditions for the if & else statements, etc... If you can provide us with your attempt and where you are having a problem with, we could help you better. For now, the question seems very broad and vague.

Comment: Please note: you learn programming first and foremost by TRYING things yourself. You shouldn't make it your first impulse to ask others for help. There are no detours in life, if YOU want to learn programming, then YOU need to spend the time to understand the assignment, and to learn how to get from requirements to a design to working code. We gladly help you FINISHING your stuff, when you have code, and you just can't find the error, after hours of trying.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you looking for but i didn't get the "h" can you explain it?

```
public void printTrident(int t, int s, int h) {         
    if ((t >= 0 && t <= 10) && (s >= 0 && s <= 10) && (h >= 0 && h <= 10)) {            
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s * s; j++) {
                    if (j % t == 0) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();           
            }       
   } else {             
       System.out.println("Please Inter Valid Number");         
   }    
}
```

Comment: basically the h is those two asterisks at the bottom of the trident in that example i gave, which is the handle of the trident. so if I input let's say, the number 7 for h, then it will have 7 asterisks as the handle of the trident.